# Extracting record values from a plain text with no xml

Tags: php, explode

1. I have trouble writing a php script with the following data in a
   plain text file. I could extract the values with Keywords, Abstract,
   https but not those ending with "comma":

---

Example:

```
name aaaaa, name bbbb, name ccccc, name dddd .....,
title............ ,   <- each title ends with a  comma
sub-title ........,   <- each sub-title ends with a  comma
56 ...............,   <- each volume  ends with a  comma
2020 ............ ,   <- each year ends with a  comma
230    ...........,   <- each nr ends with a  comma
ISSN 0012-82......,   <- each issn ends with a  
https://...........
(http:// .........)
Abstract:
Keywords:

                   <- Space
```

nth record

---

---

My script:

```
<?php
$txt   =   file_get_contents("in.txt");
$array = explode("\n\n", $txt);
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    $id_pattern = '#'.($key+1).'. (.*?).,.\n#';
    preg_match($id_pattern, $value, $id);
   //........

    $https_pattern = '#https \: (.*?)\n\n#';
    preg_match($https_pattern, $value, $https);


    $abstract_pattern = '#Abstract\: (.*?)\n#';
    preg_match($abstract_pattern, $value, $abstract);


    $keywords_pattern = '#Keywords\: (.*?)#';
    preg_match($keywords_pattern, $value, $keywords);

    $id = $id[1];
    $https = $https[1];
    $abstract = $abstract[1];
    $keywords = $keywords[1];

}
```

Comment: Is the file plain text or a CSV? Can you please add in a 10 line version of your file and what you want out of it? It is hard to see the file contents with what your provided. Please indent the example 4 spaces on each line.

Comment: It is plain text file.

Comment: Your example looks like a CSV with missing encapsulation. `authors, article title, journal, volume, publication year, pages, ISSN, DOI, URL, abstract, keywords` The `ISSN`, `doi`, and URL appear to be for a different resource though. How are you getting this file/data? (Oh, you didn't update this, this is the old format still)

Comment: Your correct . It is a CSV file and it is old. I can see that each record has Authors, Title,..issn.  But they are not specified in the record like keywords, abstract. I just want to get each record and extract the values (Author, title,  abstract ...keywords  and write them into a database.

Comment: I would look at standardizing the data (e.g. remove the new lines, that is not standard) then using https://github.com/knmnyn/ParsCit.